# SQL insert only if

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

i am trying to insert the new data if and only if, this data doesnot exist in the database, if it exists, just break the insert operation and take the next item and try to check and insertg again, i want something like this:

```
insert into db if field_id doesnot exist, if exist, dont touch anything, neither update nor anything
```

`ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` is not what i want and `INSERT IGNORE` seems to be mysterious to me now

this is my attempt:

```
$check = "SELECT anzeige_id FROM table WHERE anzeige_id = '$whatIhaveInMyHand'";
$checked=mysql_query($check);
if(mysql_num_rows($checked)==0){
$sql = "INSERT INTO table (`firmen_id`,`anzeige_id`,`anzeige_txt`) VALUES ('$firma_id','$anzeigen_id','$anzeige_txt')";
$sql_inserted = mysql_query($sql);
if($sql_inserted){
   echo "inserted into db <br/>";
}else{
  echo "anzeige_id already exists ".$anzeigen_id."<br/>";
}
```

what is good for my plan?

Comment: I would just SELECT first then INSERT if required, interested to see if there any 'one-step' methods though.

Comment: this is what i need one step method

Comment: For the love of whatever is good in this world, please tell me you're using `mysql_real_escape` on whatever it is you're getting into `$whatIhaveInMyHand` (and anything you get from the users & inline into your queries), making you SQL-injection-proof.

Comment: Is `anzeige_id` your primary key or otherwise part of a unique constraint?

Comment: first select then insert , or use INSERT IGNORE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a UNIQUE constraint on the field you are using to identify the data set if it is not already PRIMARY KEY and use INSERT IGNORE. That will result in new data set being inserted and old data sets failing to insert silently.

Comment: great, i think, this is what i am looking for

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to read first, then insert, or you'll have to trust `INSERT IGNORE`,  which will effectively ignore any row which insertion would cause a UNIQUE/PRIMARY key violation.

Answer (score 0):

Set a counter and read all the records:

```
if(counter>0) {
   record available
}
```